# can we change iphone profiles from silent to ring with iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

can we change iphone profiles from silent to ring with iphone sdk?for eg.if the iphone is in silent mode and if some person calls the user more than 4 times then the iphone mode will change to ringing mode ............i know that there are no api for this but can all ou give some other legal alternatives ,

Comment: does nobody has some point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no access to incoming phone calls or any phone call history from an app on an iPhone running a stock OS.

Comment: is there any api to change the ringtone of iphone with sdk

Comment: Again, this is Private API. You can get the headers from the internet but Apple will not approve your app.